# Flutter error: The method 'getMessage' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class WorldTime {

  String _url = 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/worldtime?city';
  String location = 'London';
  String time = '';

  WorldTime({ required this.location });

  Future<void> getTime() async {

    try {
        final response = await get(Uri.parse('$_url=$location'),
                                      // Send authorization headers to the backend.
                                      headers: {'X-Api-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'},
        );

        Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            time = "${data['hour']}:${data['minute']}";
        }
        else {
            throw new APIConnexionException(data['statusCode'], data['message']);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        print('caught api error: ${e.getMessage()}');
    }
  }
}



class APIConnexionException implements Exception {
    late String _message;
    late String _statusCode;

    APIConnexionException([ String statusCode = '', String message = 'API Exception!' ]) {
        this._message = message;
        this._statusCode = statusCode;
    }


    String getMessage() {
        return 'code: ${this._statusCode} message: ${this._message}';
    }
}
```

This is the error message I get when I run the app:

> The method 'getMessage' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
> 'Object' is from 'dart:core'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getMessage'.

I don't understand this message. The getMessage() method is defined in my class.
Why am I getting this error ?
Should I define this method differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are throwing a custom exception called `APIConnexionException` but you are catching general errors. That is why the particular method is not available.

You should catch the specific type of exception as

```
on APIConnexionException catch (e) {
    print('caught api error: ${e.getMessage()}');
}
```

Your updated code snippet:

```html
class WorldTime {

  String _url = 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/worldtime?city';
  String location = 'London';
  String time = '';

  WorldTime({ required this.location });

  Future<void> getTime() async {

    try {
        final response = await get(Uri.parse('$_url=$location'),
                                      // Send authorization headers to the backend.
                                      headers: {'X-Api-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'},
        );

        Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            time = "${data['hour']}:${data['minute']}";
        }
        else {
            throw new APIConnexionException(data['statusCode'], data['message']);
        }
    }
    on APIConnexionException catch (e) {
        print('caught api error: ${e.getMessage()}');
    }
    
    catch (e) {
        print('caught api error: ${e.toString()}');
    }
  }
}



class APIConnexionException implements Exception {
    late String _message;
    late String _statusCode;

    APIConnexionException([ String statusCode = '', String message = 'API Exception!' ]) {
        this._message = message;
        this._statusCode = statusCode;
    }


    String getMessage() {
        return 'code: ${this._statusCode} message: ${this._message}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because exception doesn't know about the type of the exception. To solve this just give the type for the Exception `e`

Like:

```
on APIConnexionException catch (e) {
      print('caught api error: ${e.getMessage()}');
    }
```